# nginx location directive doesn't look for specified file first

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a simple nginx configuration file -

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    #
    # Routing
    #

    location / { index index.html; }
    location /foo { index foo.html }

    #
    # Logging
    #

    access_log /var/log/nginx/{{ www_domain }}.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/{{ www_domain }}-error.log error;

    server_name example.com;
    charset utf-8;
}
```

As you can see, there's only 2 routes - the `/` and `/foo` paths.

- When I go to `www.example.com/` all works correctly. I can see the `index.html` page being served.
- When I go to `www.example.com/foo`, I get a 404 error when I should be getting the `foo.html` page.

Looking at the logs, I see this error:

```
2018/08/13 21:51:42 [error] 14594#14594: *6 open() "/var/www/example.com/foo" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: example.com, request: "GET /foo HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
```

The error implies that it's looking for a file named `/var/www/example.com/foo` and not `/var/www/example.com/foo.html` like I would expect.

Why does this happen in general, and specifically why does it not happen on my root path `/` ?

Thanks!

Edit: It does work if I visit `www.example.com/foo.html` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` directive will append the filename, when you give the URI of a directory.

So `/` points to the root directory (`/var/www/example.com/`), and the `index index.html;` statement causes `nginx` to return the file `/var/www/example.com/index.html`.

The `/foo` URI does not point to a directory. If the directory `/var/www/example.com/foo/`) did in fact exist, the `index foo.html;` statement would cause `nginx` to return the file `/var/www/example.com/foo/foo.html`. Which is not `/var/www/example.com/foo.html`.

What you are attempting to achieve is some kind of extension-less scheme, which is nothing to do with the `index` directive.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details of the `index` directive.

---

There are many solutions that will work, for example, using `try_files` instead of `index`:

```
location /foo { try_files /foo.html =404; }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense - looks like I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the `index` directive worked.