# Nginx throws 404 error for a file route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, plesk

I have a simple Laravel route to provide to our users private files. We present files to users with the help of a middleware. Thus, we check whether the logged in user really has access to this file.

Everything is working as expected we on local environment. But we ran into a problem when we deployed it to the server. It does not see the Laravel route file in the Nginx location and tries to find the file in the root directory.

Laravel route example as below.

```php
Route::get('lesson-attachment/{uuid}/{filename}', LessonAttachmentController::class)->name('lesson.attachment');
```

As you can see, we expect to receive a `uuid` and `filename` as url parameters. Actually the `filaname` parameter is required because we returns inline response on the exact url sometimes and we want to show the filename on the browser tab. Anyway, finally the codes here work fine on local machine.

But when we come to the nginx server, things get confused and when we look at the logs, we get the following error.

`/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/current/public/lesson-attachment/61cd7c8b-a7a1-49f8-86b8-d82825c9f55a/sample-file.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Here is the nginx conf:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;
```

The question is how can I run that url path on production server?

`https://example.com/lesson-attachment/61cd7c8b-a7a1-49f8-86b8-d82825c9f55a/sample-file.pdf`

For more information my development environment:

- Macbook Pro
- Laravel Valet

For more information our production environment:

- Ubuntu 20
- Nginx
- Plesk Panel (core nginx configurations are provided from plesk)
- Using php `deployer` tool for deployment to production.

**UPDATE** - The base `server` blocks of nginx configuration. Please note, it provides by Plesk.

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        default                    off;
        text/html                  epoch;
        text/css                   max;
        application/javascript     max;
        ~image/                    max;
        ~font/                     max;
}

server {
        listen ***** ssl http2;
        expires $expires;

        server_name example.com;

        client_max_body_size 134217728;

        # mailconfig
        location ~* ^/autodiscover/autodiscover\.xml$ {
                try_files $uri @mad;
        }
        location ~* ^(/\.well-known/autoconfig)?/mail/config\-v1\.1\.xml$ {
                try_files $uri @mad;
        }

        location  ~* ^/email\.mobileconfig$ {
                try_files $uri @mad;
        }

        location @mad {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /mailconfig/ break;

                proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:8880;
                proxy_set_header X-Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Request-URI      $request_uri;
        }
        # mailconfig

        root "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/current/public";
        access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
        error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

        #extension letsencrypt begin
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
                root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

                types { }
                default_type text/plain;
            satisfy any;
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;

                location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge.*/\. {
                        deny all;
                }
        }
        #extension letsencrypt end

        #extension sslit begin

        #extension sslit end

        #extension sectigo begin
        location ^~ /.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/pki-validation/ {
                root /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs;

                types { }
                default_type text/plain;

                satisfy any;
                auth_basic off;
                allow all;

                location ~ ^/\.well-known/pki-validation.*/\. {
                        deny all;
                }
        }
        #extension sectigo end

        error_page 400 "/error_docs/bad_request.html";
        error_page 401 "/error_docs/unauthorized.html";
        error_page 403 "/error_docs/forbidden.html";
        error_page 404 "/error_docs/not_found.html";
        error_page 500 "/error_docs/internal_server_error.html";
        error_page 405 "/error_docs/method_not_allowed.html";
        error_page 406 "/error_docs/not_acceptable.html";
        error_page 407 "/error_docs/proxy_authentication_required.html";
        error_page 412 "/error_docs/precondition_failed.html";
        error_page 414 "/error_docs/request_uri_too_long.html";
        error_page 415 "/error_docs/unsupported_media_type.html";
        error_page 501 "/error_docs/not_implemented.html";
        error_page 502 "/error_docs/bad_gateway.html";
        error_page 503 "/error_docs/maintenance.html";

        location ^~ /error_docs {
                root "/var/www/vhosts/example.com";
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(plesk-stat|awstats-icon|webstat|webstat-ssl|ftpstat|anon_ftpstat) {
                auth_basic_user_file "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/pd/d..httpdocs@plesk-stat";
                autoindex on;

                location ~ ^/plesk-stat(.*) {
                        alias /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/statistics/$1;
                }

                location ~ ^/awstats-icon(.*) {
                        alias /usr/share/awstats/icon/$1;
                }

                location ~ ^/(.*) {
                        alias /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/statistics/$1;
                }
        }

        location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
                alias /var/www/vhosts/example.com/web_users/$1/$2;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        }

        location ~ \.php(/.*)?$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
                try_files $uri $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass "unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/php-fpm.sock";
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;

        }

        index "index.html" "index.cgi" "index.pl" "index.php" "index.xhtml" "index.htm" "index.shtml";

        disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/example.com";

        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/expires.global;
        include "/var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/conf/vhost_nginx.conf";
}
```

Comment: I would avoid having `{filename}` as a URL parameter, maybe as a Query String parameter, and properly `urlencode`-ed would be better? URL would be `https://example.com/lesson-attachment/61cd7c8b-a7a1-49f8-86b8-d82825c9f55a?filename=sample-file.pdf`, then `$request->input('filename')` can be used to pull said filename from the URL.

Comment: Avoiding entering the filename provides a solution, yes. But the problem is that we preview some of our files in Google Docs Viewer. Meanwhile, the file name is displayed as `uuid` in the browser tab. Our main goal here is to show the file name as it is and the user should download the file with its original name when downloading.

Comment: That's not avoiding entering the filename, that's making the filename a Query String parameter `?filename=sample.pdf`, not a URL parameter `/sample.pdf`. The code _should_ be exactly the same, but instead of using something like `public function attachment($uuid, $filename){ ... }`, you'd do `public function attachment($uuid) { $filename = request()->input('filename'); }`; I have no idea what the rest of your comment has to do with anything, since that seems entirely dependent on your code implementation, but this should be equivalent, and actually work  If not, you might need more details.

Comment: I understand you.  But the real question is this.  Why is the code implemantation running on the local machine and why not running on the prod server?  I think this is related to nginx.  But I'm not good with nginx configurations.

Comment: Most likely, yes; locally typically use something like `php artisan serve`, with the associated `.htaccess`, or some kind of alternate webserver, docker, forge (if that's still a thing), etc. I'm in the same camp as you, I don't have a great understanding of `nginx` config, but basically, `nginx` is treating your URL as basically `https://example.com/.../sample.pdf`, but there isn't a file/folder in that directory it can serve, hence the 404. This code hasn't actually even hit Laravel at this point. Locally is quite different. You can _maybe_ try running `nginx` locally, but beyond that, ‍♂️

Comment: RE: finding the file in the root - maybe you are referring to the fact `/var/www/vhosts/...` etc appears in the log msg?  That is standard in the nginx error log, there is nothing wrong with that ([random example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831148/nginx-location-directive-doesnt-look-for-specified-file-first)).  Typically the actual request which caused the 404 will be included in that log msg (as seen in the random example I linked), though you haven't shown that part here.

Comment: Some common problems with routes between dev/production: 1) route cache. Have you tried `php artisan route:clear` on your production server? Or maybe it only works locally bcs you have a locally cached copy which still works but will break bcs of some later change? 2) If you're looking either `uuid` or `filename` up in a DB, do they exist on the prod server DB? Route-model-binding, code like `findOrFail()` etc will throw 404s if the specified item isn't in the DB.

Comment: Can you add your complete `server {}` notation from nginx to your question(dont put it in comment, there's already too much info to read.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic thank you for your comment. I did clear the cache of all routes. But the same thing, it does not works. It still shows 404 error. I think this is exactly from the nginx issue configuration or from Plesk's own settings.

I updated the content and added the main nginx config. you can check.

Comment: @ysfkaya Thanks, I see `disable_symlinks if_not_owner "from=/var/www/vhosts/example.com";` and think it might be related to ACL. Can you verify the access rights to the file are correct? If one uses root to `git pull` to pull in files on server, the `apache` user might not be able to access it.